# Is there any code to transfer the data from array into the tables of MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

Need to import the Excel sheet data (Data is related to marine ship information) into the Access tables using VBA

1. I have fixed the Import Excel Sheet template
2. I have stored the excel sheet data and the access tables information in two different arrays like : aShipInfo contains all the excel data and aTableListingSet contains all the information of the tables in the access

i'm beginner in VBA

I expect the ouptut to be: Values in the excel sheet has to transform into the particular tables in Ms Access

Answer (score 0):

Can you just query your excel spreadhseets in to Access?  If the top row of excel is headers you could do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO accessTable(Field1, Field2) " & _
" SELECT [Excel column 1], [Excel Column 2]" & _
" FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & FullFileNameAndPath & "].[SheetName$]"
```

Comment: Hello Zaider, Thanks for the reply.. but the data in excel sheet has to be aligned in different tables and fields. Can  you help me in this

Comment: @AnilUlchala Would be able to provide sample data of what an excel spreadsheet might look like and what tables it has to go into?

Comment: Stop editing out the tags from a burnination until the burnination has started. It is not up to regular users to change the tags, it just bumps posts to the front page.